# Why the result of Task scheduler is different with manually run PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I try to use PowerShell script to check all servers are up or down. The script is as below:

---

```
    ## Test Server up or down ##
## Start-Transcript -path C:\XXXX\Check_Server\output.txt -force
$names = Get-content "C:\XXXX\Check_Server\AllSQLHostName.txt"
Start-Transcript -path C:\XXXX\Check_Server\output.txt -force
foreach ($name in $names){
  if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
    Write-Host "$name,up"
  }
  else{
    Write-Host "$name,down"
  }
}

Stop-Transcript

Start-Sleep -s 5
If (Select-String -Pattern "Down" -Path C:\XXXX\Check_Server\output.txt)
{
    Send-MailMessage -To "BBBB@XXXX.com" -From "AAAA@XXXX.com" -Subject "Some Server Down" -SmtpServer "XXX.XXX.com" -Attachments "C:\XXXX\Check_Server\output.txt"
}
Else
{
    Send-MailMessage -To "BBBB@XXXX.com" -From "AAAA@XXXX.com" -Subject "All Server Up" -SmtpServer "XXX.XXX.com" -Attachments "C:\XXXX\Check_Server\output.txt"
}
```

When I manually run the script it will send me "All Server Up". But in task scheduler, it sends me "Some Server Down". And I double checked the output.txt. No server down.
BTW: The setting in task scheduler is:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file C:\XXXX\Check_Server\01_Server_Test_Server_up_or_down.ps1
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your scheduled task.  Does it have the same privileges as when you manually run it?

Comment: What account are you running the task under?  The System account doesn't have network access.  You'll want to use the Network Service account.

Comment: What user is running the script in task scheduler?

Comment: Even I click the "Run with the highest privileges" as  "https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/b19a56c3-6e59-46a9-a4dc-9858e3403a85/i-am-running-a-script-in-task-scheduler-and-need-powershell-to-run-as-admin?forum=ITCG I still got the same error.

Comment: Thank you all, they run as the same user. Thanks

Comment: *What user?*  Please be specific as to whether its LocalSystem, Local Service, or Network Service.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this for different purpose, I think it will help u as well

cmd /c "start powershell.exe -f \path*******.ps1"